# How do I serve a static SVG file with Flask?

Tags: python, mime-types, flask

I want to serve a static SVG file with Flask, but the SVG file is transferred without a `Content-Type` header. The correct mime type is `image/svg+xml`. How can I make sure that Flask uses the correct mime type for the SVG file and sends it to the browser?

I refer to the file as `/static/python.svg`, and it does exist.

I tried this in my `__init__.py` file, but it didn't make any difference:

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type('images/svg+xml', '.svg')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a mistake in your mime type. The correct one is `image/svg+xml` (note the lack of the ‘s’).

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type('image/svg+xml', '.svg')
#                        ^ no s
```

Answer (score 2):

A easy (but hacky) way is to add a new route just for svgs:

```
@app.route('/static/<svgFile>.svg')
def serve_content(svgFile):
    return file('static/'+svgFile+'.svg').read()
```